# Arabic text-shadow trouble

Tags: html, css, arabic

[image: Arabic text trouble]

```html
<html>
  <body style="font-size: 36px; background: #4488ff; color:#fff;">
    <div>
      <span>أ</span><span>ظ</span><span>ه</span><span>ر</span><span> </span><span>ا</span><span>ل</span><span>ك</span><span>ل</span>
    </div>
    <div style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;">
      <span>أ</span><span>ظ</span><span>ه</span><span>ر</span><span> </span><span>ا</span><span>ل</span><span>ك</span><span>ل</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've noticed that spanned Arabic text have gaps (tested on Chrome\FireFox). Well, I need text to be spanned and I don't think that gaps should exist, anyway I could overcome the issue?

Comment: But that's incorrect behavior according to W3 requirements: https://www.w3.org/TR/alreq/#h_joining_and_text_border (3.4.7.3 Text border)

Comment: thanks for the link, instructive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to use drop-shadow filter untill text-stroke works  :

possible example:

```css
span:nth-child(3) {
  color: gold;
}

body {
  font-size: 80px;
  background: #4488ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}

html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<div style="filter:
drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px #000)  
drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px #000)
drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px #000)  
drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px #000)
">
  <span>أ</span><span>ظ</span><span>ه</span><span>ر</span><span> </span><span>ا</span><span>ل</span><span>ك</span><span>ل</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello in Arabic there is no need to write in separate letters like English so you you need to write Full sentence with shadow for example :

```
  // modified text
<div style="text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000; color:#fff">
  أظهر الكل
</div>
```

Comment: I need text to be spanned to have an opportunity to highlight only part of the text whenever I need it: `<span style="color:red">أ</span>`.
I've noticed that `text-shadow` and `-webkit-text-stroke` make arabic text gapped.

Comment: I don't know which part to you wanna highlight but I made an example for you, wish to be helpful here : 

https://jsfiddle.net/4ku9L1qp/1/